# Sencha Touch 2 : How to get the values from an HTML input field displayed inside a Panel?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am displaying an html inside an Ext.Panel using setHtml method. The HTML is as below.

```
<html>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
</html>
```

My Panel is

```
Ext.define('WU.view.Template', {
  extend: 'Ext.Panel',
  alias: 'widget.templateview',
  config: {
    items: [{
      xtype: 'panel',
      id: 'dummyPanel',
    }]
  }
});
```

I am setting the values inside the controller as below.

```
Ext.getCmp('dummyPanel').setHtml(html file);
```

If I want to get the values from the input field 'firstname' , then how to fetch these values?

Comment: Why don't use sencha provided textfield's which come with Label and API for all operations.

Comment: Hi. I want to display an html inside the sencha Panel. This html is returned from the server so I cant use sencha provided textfield

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just query the input inside the panel's element.

[Here's an example](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#u7cHV)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help TDeBaileul. This is what I was exactly looking for.

Comment: The link does not show anything. This is one of the reasons why you should write everything inside SO. Now could you show the code?